# The easiest way to restart active directory connection (preferable from command line)

Tags: active-directory, beta, domain, big-sur

I'm currently testing my software compatibility in macOS Big Sur, and it requires connection to domain controller…

Unfortunately, in this new environment (beta version) the connection goes down after going back from sleep mode.

In order regain connectivity I've found a workaround, by removing and than re-inserting the AD connection... However, this is very time consuming.

Perhaps there's any alternative from commandline to restart the AD connection so I can use it in script automatically ?

Comment: Did you report the issue to Apple already?

Comment: Yes, I've reported on this anyway. but I wonder of there's any quick workaround to resolve this issue once occurring, using command line so I can monitor my connection using script.